# Active Record - How to perform a nested select on a second table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to list all customers along with their latest order date (plus pagination).

How can I write the following SQL query using Active Record?

```
select *,
  (
    select max(created_at)
    from orders
    where orders.customer_id = customers.id
  ) as latest_order_date
from customers
limit 25 offset 0
```

I tried this but it complains `missing FROM-clause entry for table "customers"`:

```
Customer
  .select('*')
  .select(
    Order
      .where('customer_id = customers.id')
      .maximum(:created_at)
  ).page(params[:page])

# Generates this (clearly only the Order query):
SELECT MAX("orders"."created_at") 
FROM "orders" 
WHERE (customer_id = customers.id)
```

**EDIT**: it would be good to keep AR's parameterization and [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari)'s pagination goodness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord nested SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377455/activerecord-nested-select)

Comment: Thanks, I checked the possible duplicate but it's slightly different. They select from a single table. Here, I select from two tables. So the answers there don't solve the problem in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us any information about the relationship between these two tables, so I will assume `Customer` `has_many` `Orders`.

While ActiveRecord doesn't support what you are trying to do, it is built on top of [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel), which does.

Every Rails model has a method named `arel_table` that will return its corresponding `Arel::Table`. You might want [a helper library](https://github.com/camertron/arel-helpers) to make this cleaner because the default way is a little cumbersome. I will use the plain Arel syntax to maximize compatibility.

ActiveRecord understands Arel objects and can accept them alongside its own syntax.

```
orders = Order.arel_table
customers = Customer.arel_table

Customer.joins(:orders).group(:id).select([
  customers[Arel.star],
  orders[:created_at].maximum.as('latest_order_date')
])
```

Which produces

```
SELECT "customers".*, MAX("orders"."created_at") AS "latest_order_date"
FROM "customers"
INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."customer_id" = "customers"."id"
GROUP BY "customers"."id"
```

This is the customary way of doing this, but if you still want to do it as a subquery, you can do this

```
Customer.select([
  customers[Arel.star],
  orders.project(orders[:created_at].maximum)
        .where(orders[:customer_id].eq(customers[:id]))
        .as('latest_order_date')
])
```

Which gives us

```
SELECT "customers".*, (
  SELECT MAX("orders"."created_at")
  FROM "orders"
  WHERE "orders"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" ) "latest_order_date"
FROM "customers"
```

Comment: That INNER JOIN query isn't going to execute, as you are using an aggregate function with no GROUP BY

Comment: thx for your answer. it sounds like there's no native way of using sub-selects via active record -- Arel is the only way?

Comment: @BenKoshy sub-selects work fine with `where`, but I don't believe `select` supports them, which is why I used Arel for this. You can pass an ActiveRecord scope into `where` to perform a sub-select query.

Answer (score 1):

The most Active Record-ish way I've come up with so far is:

```
Customer
  .page(params[:page])
  .select('*')
  .select(<<-SQL.squish)
    (
      SELECT MAX(created_at) AS latest_order_date
      FROM orders
      WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id
    )
  SQL
```

I still wish I could make the string part more Active Record-ish.

The `<<-SQL` is just [heredoc](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1675-using-heredoc-for-prettier-ruby-code).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same answer @adam was giving, but not using AREL and just straight ActiveRecord. Not sure it's really much better than @João Marcelo Souza

```
Customer.select("customers.*, max(orders.created_at)").joins(:orders).group("customers.id").page(params[:page])
```

(The group by avoids list all the customers columns by using [this feature of Postgres 9.1 and higher](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#SQL_and_PL.2FPgSQL_features).)

The OP doesn't say, but the query doesn't handle the case where the customer has no orders. This version does that:

```
Customer.select("customers.*, coalesce(max(orders.created_at),0)").joins("left outer join orders on orders.customer_id=customers.id").group("customers.id").page(params[:page])
```