# How to group by attribute but display value of nested attribute?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got these models in my Rails 6 application:

---

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :account

  has_many :people

end
```

---

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :client

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :client

end
```

---

In my `SharesController` I am trying to generate the **total payments** for each `client` and show them as a pie chart:

```
class SharesController < ApplicationController

  def index

        @clients = current_account.clients.joins(:payments)
                                          .where(:payments => {:date => @range, :currency => @currency})
                                          .order("sum_payments_#{@part} DESC")
                                          .group("clients.id", "clients.name")
                                          .having("sum_payments_#{@part} > 0")
                                          .sum("payments.#{@part}")
      end

end
```

The problem with this is that it groups by `client` correctly. However, rather than showing each client's `name` I want to show the `last_name` of each client's first nested `person`.

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to create a join between `Client` and `Person` and then use `uniq` to avoid duplicated clients.

You could try something like this (I'm not sure if this code works but just to make it clearer what I mean)

```rb
@clients = current_account.clients.joins(:payments, :people)
                   .where(:payments => {:date => @range, :currency => @currency})
                   .order("sum_payments_#{@part} DESC")
                   .group("clients.id", "people.last_name")
                   .having("sum_payments_#{@part} > 0")
                   .sum("payments.#{@part}")
```

Comment: @Tintin81 it was worth a second attempt so I edited the answer after some reading on ActiveRecords, but the Idea is always the same, you need to join `People` and get just one person for each client.

Comment: @Guiseppe Schembri: Thanks so much. I think I'm on the right track now. It seems to work but I will look at it again tomorrow with fresh eyes. The `.uniq` is unnecessary and breaks the code, though.

Comment: @Tintin81 I'm glad you could find the right track.  Just for future reference, I suggested `uniq`  because I thought that if you group for `"clients.id", "people.last_name"` the `sum of payments` could be over evaluated. Anyway if you need such complex queries in the future you may need to address `Arel`, have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740031/active-record-how-to-perform-a-nested-select-on-a-second-table) SO post and the [suggested library](https://github.com/camertron/arel-helpers), it could be very useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @Giuseppe Schembri. The above code worked for me, so I will mark it as the correct answer.